# Simulating probabilities in a do loop

Tags: sas

I am trying to determine the probability that the mean of a sample from a unifrom distribution lies between .4 and .5.

```
data sample1 (drop= i x z) ;
     z=0;
     do i=1 to 50;   
        x= ranuni(234);
        z= z+x;
        meanz= z/50;
        end;
     output;
run;
```

This gives me the mean, but is there some nice way in the loop to output P(.4 <= meanz <=.5).

Comment: With a second loop ? Like calculate the mean for N samples of M observations, and plot the N means you obtain, or count the number of times it is in the 0.4 0.5 interval. It is also a function of M, so keep that in mind.

Comment: I thought about a second loop and doing counts, but I was thinking more interms of the Central Limit Theorem with the expected value equal to .5, but it doesn't seem like this can work in a loop.

Comment: Please be more specific in what you want then. Do you want a theoretical result ? in which case what do you want to simulate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

It gives you the average of 100 `meanz` and the percentage of them between .4 and .5.

```
data sample1 (drop= i x z sim) ;
between4_5 = 0;
meanz = 0;
do sim=1 to 100;
     z=0;
     do i=1 to 50;   
        x= ranuni(234);
        z= z+x;
     end;
     meanz = meanz + z/(50*100);
     if .4 < z/50 < .5 then
        between4_5 = between4_5 + 1/100;
end;
output;
run;
```